# SQLite NOT NULL constraint not working with INSERT OR IGNORE

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am with Python 2.7 and SQLite3.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (transctionid text not null collate nocase primary key,
             trans text,
             symbol text not null,
             qty real,
             price real)''')
purchases = [('B1Jan', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('C2Jan', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('D3Jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('d3jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('E5Jan', 'SELL', '', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
conn.commit()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
    print row
conn.close()
```

The result is:

```
(u'B1Jan', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0)
(u'D3Jan', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)
(u'', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)
(u'E5Jan', u'SELL', u'', 500.0, 53.0)
(u'C2Jan', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000.0, 72.0)
```

**INSERT OR IGNORE only works with the "PRIMARY KEY" constraint. The "NOT NULL" constraint is not working.**

According to http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html :

> For the INSERT and UPDATE commands, the keywords "ON CONFLICT" are
>   replaced by "OR" so that the syntax reads more naturally. For example,
>   instead of "INSERT ON CONFLICT IGNORE" we have "INSERT OR IGNORE". ... The
>   ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints (and to
>   PRIMARY KEY constraints which for the purposes of this section are the
>   same thing as UNIQUE constraints).

The result I expected is:

```
(u'B1Jan', u'BUY', u'IBM', 1000.0, 45.0)
(u'D3Jan', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)
(u'C2Jan', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000.0, 72.0)
```

By the way, how do I know which row is INSERTED successfully and which row is IGNORED ON CONFLICT?

Answer (score 2):

The empty string does not count as a `NULL`, but as a 0-length string.

Use `None` instead if you expect a SQL `NULL` to be inserted:

```
purchases = [('B1Jan', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('C2Jan', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('D3Jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('d3jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             (None, 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('E5Jan', 'SELL', None, 500, 53.00),
            ]
```

See the [SQLite and Python types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite-and-python-types) section of the `sqlit3` documentation.

If you need to know if rows were inserted successfully, insert one by one with `cursor.execute()` and check `cursor.rowcount` afterwards; the `.rowcount` reflects the number of affected rows, for your `.executemany()` call with `NULL` values the rowcount is `3`, with no information as to what rows succeeded and what rows failed.

Comment: By the way, how do I know which row is INSERTED successfully and which row is IGNORED ON CONFLICT?

Comment: The INSERT one-by-one and ROWCOUNT method seems to be very ineffective and time consuming. Is there a better method?

Comment: No, there isn't. The `OR IGNORE` documentation is explicit about there not being an error, and the only other feedback we have is the rowcount.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is not the same as NULL. Replace `''` with `None`:

If you want to know which rows violate contraints, remove the `OR IGNORE` and handle the `sqlite3.IntegrityError`. Code sample below inserts rows one by one and prints (could be modified to write to file, log an errors table, etc) so you know which values couldn't be inserted and why:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (transctionid text not null collate nocase primary key,
             trans text,
             symbol text not null,
             qty real,
             price real)''')
purchases = [('B1Jan', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('C2Jan', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('D3Jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('d3jan', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             (None, 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
             ('E5Jan', 'SELL', None, 500, 53.00)]
for purchase in purchases:
    try:
        c.execute('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchase)
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print "Couldn't insert row {}:\n {}".format(purchase, e)
        pass
conn.commit()
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
    print row
conn.close()
```

Comment: By the way, how do I know which row is INSERTED successfully and which row is IGNORED ON CONFLICT?